# SwiftUI - Inherited Object in ListView (and binding to selection)

Tags: ios, swift, listview, generics, swiftui

I have a ListView that is a few levels deep in a NavigationView. The idea is when a user selects an item in the ListView, the item is stored and the UI pops back to the root NavigationView.

### Specific Implementation (Working)

```swift
class SpecificListItem: ObservableObject, Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
  
  var id: String
  var kind: String
  var name: String
  var mimeType: String
  
  init(id: String, kind: String, name: String, mimeType: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.kind = kind
    self.name = name
    self.mimeType = mimeType
  }
  
  static func == (lhs: DriveListItem, rhs: DriveListItem) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id &&
      lhs.kind == rhs.kind &&
      lhs.name == rhs.name &&
      lhs.mimeType == rhs.mimeType
  }
  
  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(self.id)
  }
  
  func processItem() {
    // do backend stuff
  }
}

...

struct SpecificListView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var selectedItem: SpecificListItem
  // load excluded for brevity
  @ObservedObject var item: MyResponse<SpecificListResponse>

  var body: some View {
    List(selection: $selectedItem, content: {
      ForEach(item.data?.files ?? []) {
        file in HStack {
          Text(file.name)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
          // pop to root view
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

This was good for a proof of concept. Now I need to add a layer of abstraction.

---

### Attempt at Generic Implementation

The selected item in this view should be generic. I have the following protocol and class defined that the selected item should conform to:

```swift
protocol SelectableItem: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
  var id: String { get set }
  func process()
}

class GenericListItem: SelectableItem {
  var id: String = ""
  var name: String = ""
  
  init () { }
  
  init(id: String) {
    self.id = id
  }
  
  static func == (lhs: GenericListItem, rhs: GenericListItem) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
  }
  
  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(self.id)
  }
  
  func process() {
    // do backend stuff
  }
}

class SpecificListItem: GenericListItem {
  var type: String
  
  init () { }

   init(id: String) {
     self.id = id
   }

   override func process() {
    // do backend stuff
   }
}
...

struct GenericListView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var selectedItem: GenericListItem 
  // load excluded for brevity
  @ObservedObject var item: MyResponse<SpecificListItem>

  var body: some View {
    List(selection: $selectedItem, content: {
      ForEach(item.data?.files ?? []) {
        file in HStack {
          Text(file.name)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
          // pop to root view
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The selected item can have it's own data elements, but I am at least expecting each item to have an `id` and a `process()` method that interacts with my backend.

However, when I try to bind the `selectedItem` in the ListView, I get the following error: `Generic parameter 'SelectionValue' could not be inferred`.

I am assuming this is because the types do not match. I have read there isn't really any dynamic or run-time type binding possible in Swift? Is this true?

I am a little more experienced in Java, and I know I could achieve this through generics and polymorphism.

`SpecificListItem` ***IS-A*** `GenericListItem` yet Swift doesn't seem to like the design. (And `MyResponse` has-a `SpecificListItem`).

***How can I define a generic class that can be selected from many child views and bound at the root view, yet can be inherited to implement their own specific logic?***

---

#### Edit

My abstraction layer explanation was unclear if not just wrong. So I tried to fix that.

Adding some more information surrounding the code structure and design. Maybe it will help give some more background and context on what I am trying to accomplish.

Here is a small representation of the object interactions:

[image: class interactions]

The idea is I will have many detail views in the application. The backend will return various response types, all conforming to `SelectableItem`. In this case, the detail view item source is of type `SpecificListItem`.

And here is the interaction between the user, backend, and UI:

[image: application interactions]

And the idea here being:

- User navigates to Detail View
- Backend call is made, returns a list of `SpecificListItem`
- List View is populated with items of type `SpecifcListItem`.
- When a user selects an item from Detail View, the application pops back to root, and the `selectedItem` is set in the root view which is of type `GenericListItem`.

Comment: What is `GenericItem`? How is this related to `GenericListItem` and how both are related to `GenericListResponse`?

Comment: I added some more detail. Hope it helps... thanks.